# User uneditable JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-chrome, gps

A user arrives to place X, grabs her cellphone with the purpose of registering her geographical coordinates with the help of her GPS and of a web app (Google Chrome).

The obtained coordinates are then sent to the server in the form: 
https://example.com/registerCoords.php?latitud=0.123&longitud=0.321

This is easily edited by the user... she could get the coordinates of any other place and paste them in the above. And done... She would really be in Paris but she would 'fool' the system making it believe she is in other place.

Is there a way that a JavaScript function is loaded and executed automatically as soon as user logs into the app? Then calculates the coordinates and sends them to the server. Also, the data sent has to be uneditable by the user, as well as the function that calculates them.

The only thing the user must be able of doing is to call the function. No more. Not editing it, Not passing arguments. Anything.

Our users have Android phones using the latest version of Chrome and the permission that Chrome asks when the location is required by the web app, has been granted by our users to our app.

Thanks in advance for any idea you could give me.

Comment: "Also, the data sent has to be uneditable by the user, as well as the function that calculates them.", this is simply not possible. You can add layers of obfuscation and encryption to make it difficult, but in the end, they can simply pass false telemetry data to the browser if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Specs explicitly states:

"Common sources of location information include Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input. No guarantee is given that the API returns the device's actual location."

https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#introduction

So there is not method to prevents user inputs by specs. You can apply various control mechanism such determining if location is plausible given past array of location traversed, but nothing else.